# how to show different pop up window based on selected tab

Tags: c#, datagrid, tabcontrol

I am creating an app that is using a tabbed view. I currently am able to double click on a line in the datagrid and a new window appears where I am able to edit contents of the selected line. I now have one tab that will need a different pop up window than the rest of the tabs. How do make the one tab show a different popup window than the rest of the tabs when double clicked? Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: How are you implementing the popup window?  If it's in your own codebehind then I'd place some indicator in the TabItem's "Tag" property that was used to choose the popup (including the popup itself, since the Tag takes any object).

Comment: Why not just display the window you desire according to the currently selected tab? This does not seem difficult. Perhaps you should include some code to demonstrate what you are attempting to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [TabControl.SelectedTab](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selectedtab.aspx) property to see if currently visible tab is the one you want:

```
OnClick()
{
  if (this.tabControl.SelectedTab == this.secondTab)
  {
    // Show different popup here
  }
  else
  {
    // Show common popup here
  }
}
```